# How to convert rows to columns using tablelayout dynamically in Android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have a tablelayout that gets data dynamically. and I would like to convert the rows to columns. I changed orientation but didnt work.

```
    TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) second_row_b.findViewById(R.id.table_current_picks);

    List<PickGame> selectedPicks = buildSelectedPicks(response);
    int selectedPicksSize = selectedPicks.size() > 5 ? 5 : selectedPicks.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedPicksSize; i++) {
        TableRow rowView = (TableRow) inflater.inflate(R.layout.include_current_picks_row, null);
        TableLayout.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0, 0.1f);
        tableLayout.addView(rowView, rowParams);
        PickGame pickGame = selectedPicks.get(i);
        TextView totalPointsText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text_total_points);
        TextView gamePointsText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text_game_points);
        NetworkImageView imageView = (NetworkImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image_team_pick);
```

and this is my XML

```
    <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table_current_picks"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Why you don't use an `ListView` with `Adapter` to populate your layout dinamically? I think you cannot do this with `TableLayout` because it's an static element, like all *Layout elements.

Comment: Thank you but I need to do something like this.

Comment: I tried to add image but I couldnt. I am trying to do something like this:  Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 are all imageview comes from server. and I have 2 rows that related which are data related to each column also come from server. So how can I use listview to add each column with its own row data?

Comment: Did you try adding a vertical orientation to the table ROW and not just the table LAYOUT? (include_current_picks_row.xml)